# How to use php-cli in interactive mode, in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, php

I wanted to quick test a small snippet of PHP code. So, After doing a little search I setup php5-cli using synaptic on my Ubuntu machine.

Now when I tried to run

```
$ php -a
```

I get a php prompt. But I am unable to get it to work. I tried :

```
php > echo 'hi there!'
    >
    >

php > <?php echo 'hi there!' ?>
    > 
    >
```

But, nothing seems to work! What am I doing wrong?

[Note: I am not very familiar with PHP]

[Update :

I wish to achieve something like :

```
    php > $url = myurl
    > $ch = curl_init();
    > curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    > $body = curl_exec($ch);
    > curl_close($ch);
    > 
    > echo $body
```

]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to terminate your statements with a semicolon.

```
php > echo "hello"
php > ;
hello
php > echo "oh!";
oh!
php >
```

Comment: Oh! thats it! That works! 

Ah, juggling between languages sometime makes you do some stupid mistakes. :-)

Thanks Mark!

Answer (score 1):

It will work like this:

```
php -r "echo 'hello';"
```

Comment: Yes, It does. But, I wish to test a set of statements in interactive mode, like a perl or a python interpreter, with its own prompt. And -a seems to do the job. But I can't get it to work.

Thanks!